# Weblogic 10 loads wrong library

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have Weblogic 10.3.6.0 which I install my application to. But, one functionality could not run because (according to log file) `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setLoadEntityBytesLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;`.

I've checked the application I deployed. It only includes one library containing XmlOptions which has that method.

I strongly suspect that there was another library with different version loaded at the time. I don't know if I'm wrong but I found this:

```
->> for i in `find /software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/modules/ -name "*.jar"`; do f=`/software/bea/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin/jar -tvf $i | grep "org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class"`; if [ "$f" != "" ]; then echo "On $i: $f"; fi ; done
On /software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/modules/com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.2.0.0.jar:  10904 Thu Jan 11 11:34:24 GMT 2007 org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class
On /software/bea/Middleware/wls/10.3.6/modules/com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.2.0.0_2-5-1.jar:  11836 Thu Jul 14 12:38:04 BST 2011 org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.class
```

I've checked also in Deployments menu of WebConsole. It showed me that I don't have any shared libraries deployed.

My question is: 
1. Do JAR files inside the modules directory cause the conflict?
2. If not, what else the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is a problem happened in POI 3.14 library.

This is actually complicated. For meantime, I use the later version of POI which is still in beta (3.15 beta 1).

You can refer detailed solution on http://www.simosh.com/article/dgfacgbh-exception-when-using-apache-poi-to-read-xlsx-file.html